# Anonymous class defined in an interface VS. Concrete class outside of an interface

Tags: java, interface

In some cases, for example, in strategy pattern, I have to provide some default class of an interface.

In that case, I usually make a concrete class of an interface in a different java file as below.

```
public interface MyStrategy {
    void doSomething();
}

public class DefaultMyStrategy implements MyStrategy {
    @Override 
    public void doSomething() {
    }
}
```

But recently, I saw some code that contains an anonymous class in an interface, and it looks like as below.

```
public interface MyStrategy {

    MyStrategy DEFAULT = new MyStrategy() {
        @Override 
        public void doSomething() {
        }
    };

    void doSomething();
}
```

Which one's better for making the default class?

As I see it, `MyStrategy strategy = MyStrategy.DEFAULT;` is better than `MyStrategy strategy = new DefaultMyStrategy();`.

However, I wonder if the second one is widely used.

Comment: Well, I don't think there's a real difference, I think preference of either is a matter of taste.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That really depends on your use cases. In your 2nd case, you will get below behavior.

1. By default `MyStrategy DEFAULT` will be `public static final`. That means you can't `reinitialize` it at any point in time.
2. The `same reference` will be shared where you use `MyStrategy.DEFAULT`. If the object is `mutable` and you are `mutating` then you may face some issue.
3. The object will be created on the first use when and will `not be eligible for GC` until class loader unloads the class.

But in the case of `MyStrategy strategy = new DefaultMyStrategy();` you will get  new instance every time you use `new DefaultMyStrategy();`.

Now use case is in your hand.

Comment: Thank you for the kind answer. It helped me to understand differences between them. It seems the second one is OK for my current purpose!

Comment: “If the object is immutable and you are mutating…” makes no sense. Probably you meant “if the object is *mutable*”. Further, the instance will *not* be created eagerly when the class is loaded, but lazily when the class is initialized. [The specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se11/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.4.1) lists precisely under which conditions class initialization will occur, simply said, if the interface has no `default` methods, the initialization will only happen when a constant of the interface is actually used.

Comment: @Holger About your second point, I have tried to test with and without default method but found in both case it initializes the object on the first usage.

Comment: Perhaps, the setup was not sufficient to highlight the difference. When an interface has default methods, initializing a class which implements the interface will trigger the interface’ initialization. Without default methods, it won’t, so you could use the implementing class, even invoke methods on it via the interface, without the interface ever being initialized. When the implementing class (or any other code) accessing `static final` variable, it will trigger the initialization, if it didn’t happen already.